# C++ overloaded template functions in derived classes

Tags: c++, templates

I know you can overload templates based on their template parameters:

```
template <class T> void test() {
    std::cout << "template<T>" << std::endl;
}
void test() {
    std::cout << "not a template" << std::endl;
}
```

then inside some function:

```
test<int>();
test();
```

will correctly resolve which of the 2 different versions of test() you want. However, if I now do this inside classes with inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
    void test() {
       std::cout << "A::Test: not a template" << std::endl;
    }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    template <class T>
    void test() {
       std::cout << "B::Test: template<T>" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

then inside a function:

```
B b;
b.test<int>();
b.test();
```

`b.test<int>();` works but `b.test();` does not:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘B::test()’
note: candidate is:
note: template<class T> void B::test()
```

Why is this/ is there any way to make it correctly resolve the 2 versions based on the template arguments?

Comment: This looks like a case of the "Hiding Rule" but with template implied. Take a look at this link, it might be of help: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, a name defined in a derived class hides uses of the same name in a base class. To hoist the name in the base class into the derived class, add

```
using A::test;
```

to the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

What you are observing is called name hiding. The name `test` in the derived class hides `test` in the base class. Without a `using` declaration that name will never be found when called through the exact type of that object (casting to base or explicitly qualifying the call also helps).